# Getting error when trying to install php in raspbian image on docker

Tags: php, docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm getting error saying E: Unable to locate package php
when installing php in raspbian image on docker.

I've pulled the raspbian/jessie image from docker hub and run it.
and in this container I've used 1.apt update 2. apt upgrade 3. apt install apache2

then tried to install php

all looked fine untill apt install apache2

```
root@516cf9de5248:/# apt install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@516cf9de5248:/# apt install php php-fpm php-curl php-gd php-intl php-mbstring php-mysql php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc php-zip libapache2-mod-php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php
E: Unable to locate package php-fpm
E: Unable to locate package php-curl
E: Unable to locate package php-gd
E: Unable to locate package php-intl
E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package php-mysql
E: Unable to locate package php-xml
E: Unable to locate package php-xmlrpc
E: Unable to locate package php-zip
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php
```

I've tried apt-get update after but still doesn't work

Comment: Shouldn't your command be like `apt-get install php`?

Comment: yea I've tried again using apt-get too in another container but it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo apt-get install php5` worked for me, even if it's not the best for security.